# How would you map nicknames ( pete,andy,Nick,Rob) to real names?

Tags: sql, facebook

I couldn't think of much except using joins if there are 2 separate tables that store names and nicknames based on account number. This is a Facebook question. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with how to solve this question?

Comment: Sounds like a good approach.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I thought may be I was missing something & may be they expect a different solution for problems like these.